# Batch script to send commands to gracefully shutdown multiple Spigot Minecraft servers

Tags: batch-file, jar, minecraft, bukkit

I'm wondering if it possible to make a windows batch script send commands to three already running .jar file instances. 
In this case the open .jar files correspond to a **bungeeCord** instance, a **survival** instance and a **hub** instance. Each of 
these .jar instances together, form the entire Spigot Minecraft server. (See the images)

[image: survival .jar instance][image: hub .jar instance][image: bungeeCord .jar instance]

Currently in order to close each of these servers/.jar instances gracefully you need to manually type in the 'stop'
command in the command line interface of both the **survival** and **hub** instance. And you have to type 'end' to shut down
the **bungeeCord** instance gracefully.

In order to automate this process I would like to write a batch script that allows me to send the **'stop'** and **'end'** commands
to the currently running .jar instances in one click, rather than having to type each command out manually on each .jar 
instance.

I've actually already managed to automate the start up of each .jar instance process by writing the following batch script 
which may help:

```
echo off

cd D:\Projects\Servers\"CRAFT412 Server Desktop"\BungeeCord
start "BungeeCord" java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar BungeeCord.jar

cd D:\Projects\Servers\"CRAFT412 Server Desktop"\hub
start "hub" java -Xms512M -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot.jar

cd D:\Projects\Servers\"CRAFT412 Server Desktop"\survival
start "survival" java -Xms512M -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot.jar
```

Upon running this script all three required .jar instances are opened and ran like the image above.

It may also help if you can see the folder structure as well so I've provided an image of that:

[image]

The start.bat file corresponds to the code above to startup all three .jar instances.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Open on Windows a command prompt window and run `taskkill /?`. The command `taskkill` __without__ option `/F` results in sending to running application the event message to gracefully terminate as Windows itself does also on shutting down. It is a matter of the application (Java in your case) if the event message to terminate is interpreted and results in closing the application. You can use the command `tasklist` to see the running processes to know the strings to use `taskkill` for the 3 running Java applications.

Comment: @Mofi Okay thanks, i'll have look into that.

Comment: See also [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/) and [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx). There are lots of questions and answers on Stack Overflow as well as on Super User regarding `taskkill` which should be helpful for you to find the right commands to gracefully terminate those three Java applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not use `taskkill`, killing the process results data loss!**
I found a nice tool called [SendMessage](https://tools.stefankueng.com/SendMessage.html) it can send keys to processes. I wrote a little batch script, but it has some errors and I can't find the sources of these errors, but if you repair the code you have a working batch script for your problem. *(I know that I shouldn't post not working code as answer, but it contains the logic and you can form this code as you want.)*

```
@echo off
cls

::Declare servers by title
::For BungeeCord servers add "BCS" prefix
set servers[0]=BCStest1 
set servers[1]=test2
set servers[2]=test server

::Servers in the array minus 1
set len=2
::Loop trought the servers
for /l %%s in (0,1,%len%) do (
    ::Set the server variable to the current server, depending on the loop number
    set server=%servers[%%s]%
    
    ::Testing for the server type
    if "BCS"=="%server:~0,3%" (
    ::If it's a BungeeCord server
    
        ::Removing the prefix
        set server=%server:~3%
        
        ::Sending shutdown command
        echo Sending shutdown command to server: %server%
        
        ::e
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:101 /lparam:1
        ::n
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:110 /lparam:1
        ::d
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:100 /lparam:1
        :: ENTER
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:13 /lparam:1
    
    ) else (
    ::If it's a normal server
    
        ::Sending shutdown command
        echo Sending shutdown command to server: %server%
        
        ::s
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:115 /lparam:1
        ::t
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:116 /lparam:1
        ::o
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:111 /lparam:1
        ::p
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:112 /lparam:1
        :: ENTER
        SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:%server% /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:13 /lparam:1
    )
)

::If the execution gets here it was successfull
echo Stop command was sent to all server!
pause
```

*(Sorry, I used batch realy long time ago, this is the reson for that I can't provide fully working code.)*
And don't forget to download the `SendMessage-1.1.2.exe` and put it into the same directory as the *.bat file!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

Or you name all your servers e.g **server** (use *title Server* in start script)
and then

```
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM java.exe /FI "Server"
```

You may also name the server like

1. Server - CityBuild
2. Server - Lobby
   ...

Then use

```
@echo off
taskkill /F /IM java.exe /FI "Server*"
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't completely answers to the question but I think it is still useful to notice :

I just found out that if you close the right window the server (.jar instance) actually shuts down properly.
So using the SendMessage tool that Noel Nemeth suggested, something as simple as that worked for me :

```
@echo off
SendMessage64.exe /message:16 /windowtitle:"Minecraft server"
```

You might also be able to use `taskkill` for this, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

For the bungeeCord instance I have no idea as I've never used it.